# How to install comands ./configure, make, install in an offline ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: networking, drivers, server, wireless

I am in a location where I can only use my mobile wifi tethering & hotspot. I downloaded and installed linux 20.04 server but unfortunately those titled commands are not included. And to get them i have to have internet using the apt and that is not possible for me now.
1- I am not sure why such commands are not included in the ISO files.
2- in such case I need your help
a- How to download,install and configure drivers for a USB wifi adapter.
b- How to configure the USB wifi network.
c- How to download and install and configure the installation commands.
only
I can reach the internet through tethering between my mobile and my laptop.

Comment: Some Ubuntu Server users compile their own software; most do not. Advice: You might find it *much* simpler to have a friend download Ubuntu Desktop for install upon your laptop.

Comment: FYI `./configure` would be a script that is provided by the package you're trying to build - it's not a command that can be installed in the same way as `make` or `install`

Answer (score 0):

You stated "I can reach the internet through tethering between my mobile and my laptop" - So you can?

**In this case:**

Enable main repository in Software & Updates (or by editing /etc/apt/sources.list).

Then run these commands in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

**If you don't have internet**:

You can download the package on another computer/to an USB drive (e.g. here: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-armhf/build-essential_12.8ubuntu1_armhf.deb.html). Make sure to choose the right package for your CPU architecure as well as the required packages if you do not have them!

You can then install the package offline using `dpkg -i <path/to/file.deb>`

**Last but not least**
I only answered the "offline" part for build-essential. The same way, you can install any package (you only have to find it, download it and run `dpkg -i <file>`). For configuring your WIFI USB, please ask another question (or browse the answers already given to other questions of this nature). Asking/answering only one certain question at a time keeps askubuntu clean and usable for others.

If you want all your questions to be solved on one page, you may look for a forum and open a thread there (this site is not a forum, but a Question&Answer page, which works a bit differently). That said, best of luck and happy fiddling.